# Не верно работает JS

Tags: javascript, битрикс

Здравствуйте! Я в JS ничего не понимаю, но жизнь требует.  Делаю интуитивно и с помощью гугла. И уже запуталась. В карточке сайта (сайт на битриксе) есть два пользовательских условия, которые не могут выполняться одновременно : администратор либо задает видимую зону текста, после которой текст сворачивается (в нижеприведенном скрипте это первое условие), а второе поле задает запрет на сворачивание текста (это второе условие). Но эта вся "красота" не работает как надо. Если я заполняю поле "видимая зона текста", то текст не сворачивается, а остается открытым.

Какие нужно внести изменения в скрипт, чтобы все работало корректно?

HTML

```
<div class="show_text">
  <div id="detail_text_resize" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('detail_text_minimize').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.overflow='';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.height='auto';" style="display:none;"><img src="картинка.png">показать полностью</div>
  <div id="detail_text_minimize" onclick="this.style.display='none';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.height='<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']?>';document.getElementById('detail_text_resize').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('detail_text').style.overflow='hidden';" style="display:none;"><img src="картинка.png">свернуть</div>
</div>
```

Сам скрипт

```
function resize_text_field(){
        if(document.getElementById("detail_text").offsetHeight > 200){
            document.getElementById("detail_text").style.overflow = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("detail_text").style.height = "<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']?>";
            document.getElementById("detail_text_resize").style.display = "";
        }//else
            //document.getElementById("detail_text_resize").style.display = "";
    }
    resize_text_field();
    onload = function(){ resize_text_field() }
        else {
        if(document.getElementById("detail_text").style.height = "<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['NO_RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']?>";
           document.getElementById("detail_text_resize").style.display = "block";
        }//else
            //document.getElementById("detail_text_resize").style.display = "block";
    }
    resize_text_field();
    onload = function(){ resize_text_field() }
```

Comment: К сожалению, не понятно, чтО нужно. Как все это выглядит и как должно работать

Comment: @maxkuku есть текст карточки, назовем это описанием. Сейчас по умолчанию в коде прописано, что если этот текст больше 200рх в высоту, то он сворачивается до 93рх. А стало необходимо, чтобы сворачиваемость этого текста была регулируемой. Для этого создано пользовательское поле в битрикс "Видимая зона текста", где указанная цифра задает видимую зону текста при сворачивании. Не те прописанные 93рх.Значение 0 вообще отменяет функцию сворачивания текста, какого бы размера он не был

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что пришло в результате попытки повторить:

везде, где есть

```
style.height = "<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']?>"
```

и вообще в скрипте

```
style.height
```

не хватает "px" после цифры.
То есть должно быть

```
style.height = "<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['RESIZE_TEXT']['VALUE']?>px"
```